# How can we perform automated tests on Chrome packaged apps (ex. Chromebook apps) using InternJS

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, intern, chromebook

I need to automate tests for Chrome packaged App & Android App on Chromebook and Nexus 10 respectively. I'm using InternJS to write automate tests for browser version of the app in Chrome. Can InternJS automate the tests for Chrome Packaged App and Android Apps?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can start Chrome using the `--load-and-launch-app` argument and then interact with the packaged app using the normal Intern functional testing APIs:

```js
// In intern.js
define({
  environments: [
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      chromeOptions: {
        args: [ 'load-and-launch-app=/path/to/app' ]
      }
    }
  ],

  // ...
});
```